# Change of boxplot after insertion of main, why?

Tags: r, boxplot

Why does the boxplot change after I insert title?

```
setwd("/microArray/A") 
data=read.celfiles(list.celfiles())
dim(data)
Features  Samples 
292681       15

boxplot(data)
```

[image: Boxplot 1]

and after inserting the title:

```
boxplot(data, main ="Boxplot A")
```

[image]

Comment: What changed? (Other than the title.)

Comment: @zephryl The whiskers' upper limits. Compare the first 6 of each plot.

Comment: You should contact the package maintainer, see `maintainer('oligo')`.

Comment: I think the boxes got rearranged (both the order and the colours), it's not clear without the axis labels

Comment: The arrangement of the boxplots always remain the same. I have looked again

Comment: Try plotting with `boxplot(data, main ="Boxplot A", las=2)`, with x axis labels rotated (`las = 2`)

Comment: Tried it and the boxplot looks a bit better, but unfortunately there is still a difference.

Comment: try to remove very extreme values from your samples or change the font size of your x labels

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: try setting `set.seed(75420433)` before each `boxplot` call : (not sure which methid might be getting called but there may be somre random sampling being done due to the size of your data, see [this](https://github.com/benilton/oligo/blob/1124ae1708c8a98263aa953632b686818b7b4bdd/R/methods-ExpressionSet.R#L9) or [this](https://github.com/benilton/oligo/blob/1124ae1708c8a98263aa953632b686818b7b4bdd/R/methods-FeatureSet.R#L128)